# Manually inserting record into linked table MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

New to VBA and Access so hope I can explain this correctly.

I have two tables , Orders and Deliveries.

Orders include OrderNo, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerContact and so on.

Deliveries include DeliveryNo, OrderNo, DeliveryDate, DeliveryType and so on.

I have created a relationship between these two tables linking them between OrderNo as I require the CustomerName when creating a Delivery from an Order.

However sometimes a Delivery is manually inserted into the table using a form. A CustomerName is required for this record but there is now no corresponding OrderNo.

I am not sure how to set up my table to accommodate manual entries.
Appreciate the help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the business requirement is to be able to insert deliveries into the delivery table without a corresponding order number. If this is the case, you need to relax the constraints on the table and remove relationship between Delivery.OrderNo and the Orders table. Otherwise, you could populate this field with a special number (0 or -1) to indicate no order in this circumstance if you need to enforce the foreign key relationship for other reasons. It all depends on how you wish to enforce the business logic.

Comment: If I remove the relationship, how will I be able to view the CustomerName for that Delivery, as each Delivery must have a CustomerName, but that value sits in the Orders table and is linked through the OrderNo in each table. I also tried using a special number, but I get a message saying 'the Database cannot find a record in the table Orders with key matching fields OrderNo'. OrderNo was set to 0

Comment: In that case, what you should probably do is insert a new entry to the Orders table with default values for the unknown fields, and place your customer number into the field which links your order item to that customer. Have some way of indicating that this is a 'manual' order so your reports make sense, e.g. by adding a 'Yes/No' column for 'ManualOrder'. If this does not solve the problem, what might also be useful for myself and others reviewing this is to post a data diagram as part of your original question showing your data model.

Comment: @Imrann, Your relationships should be in your queries or your record sources which are bound to your forms and reports. They should not be set at the table level themselves.  This simplifies the setup and prevents errors like this from occuring.  You shouldn't need them at the table level since none of your users have access to the tables themselves.  right....?

Answer (score 0):

**What if you just added a CustomerName field to the form?**

For what I understood of your question, you use the Orders table to generate the Deliveries, so for each order in the Orders table you would add/generate a record to the Deliveries table. Now, when you add a delivery manually(using the form) I suppose there is no order associated with it, hence no Customer Name. In that case the only solution would be to add a field called CustomerName to the mentioned form (I suppose the person who is manually inserting the Delivery knows the name of the customer) and any other field you need, and if your business logic requires it you can create a "virtual" Order with the same OrderNo as the inserted delivery.